# Insert Blank keyframes like in Flash

Tags: objects, video-sequence-editor, keyframes, grease-pencil, dopesheet

I am making animatics in Blender and it is turning out to be very painful. I have to draw in GP, Give camera timing in Dope Sheet.
I need to know if there is any shortcut so that I can insert blank keyframe in GP and the same reflects in the dopesheet, like you use F5 in Flash. Else I have to time in GP and again move camera in dopesheet.

Comment: If you worked through the VSE, this add-on will help to organize the process with ease: https://github.com/samytichadou/blender_project_manager
https://blenderartists.org/t/bpm-blender-project-manager/1223236
Basically the process is generating a blender file(change this to be a GP draw file), and each time you make a new scene(through the add-on), it'll be a new GP scene(one scene for each shot). This scene is added to the VSE timeline, from where you can quickly toggle back and forth between scenes. In the vse you can also have an audio sync track

Comment: If you're making animatics to a screenplay in the fountain format, this add-on will add timed dialogue etc. as text strips in the vse timeline: https://github.com/gabrielmontagne/blender-addon-unfurl-fountain

Comment: Thanks @tintwotin, let me chek it out.